# Proper way to update specific record on the LIST/SET in Redis

Tags: php, mysql, redis, crud

I'm planning to use Redis as my 2nd class database for my PHP API (Predis for PHP & Redis connection), my main database is MySQL. I am new to it and I'm wondering if I'm on right path or I'm completely doing it wrong.

I will use Redis for all "SELECT" or Retrieval queries instead of getting it from MySQL. Here's the sample flow.

I have a user who has multiple record on other table (1:many). TableA contains all the users and TableB contains all experience records of all users.

```
**TableA**
UserID - 1234
UserID - 4567
UserID - 7890

-------------------------------------------------------


**TableB**
ExperienceID - 1    |   UserID - 1234   |   Experience - Waiter
ExperienceID - 2    |   UserID - 1234   |   Experience - Chef
ExperienceID - 3    |   UserID - 4567   |   Experience - Developer
ExperienceID - 4    |   UserID - 4567   |   Experience - Technician
ExperienceID - 5    |   UserID - 4567   |   Experience - Support
ExperienceID - 6    |   UserID - 7890   |   Experience - Engineer
ExperienceID - 7    |   UserID - 7890   |   Experience - Engineer
ExperienceID - 8    |   UserID - 7890   |   Experience - Draftsman
```

- Save new experience on MySQL and once success it will push the same experience on Redis (on redis format).
- Get/Retreive all records from Redis instead of MySQL
- Update the experience on MySQL and once success it will update the specific experience on Redis ---> *I don't know how to do this on Redis without looping it on PHP which is not good idea if I have huge list of records* :(

Here is my layout in Redis.

```
uid:1234:experience
uid:4567:experience
uid:7890:experience
```

Inside of the record experience namespace

I used SADD with json encoded data to set

```
$userExperience1 = array(
    'id'            => 1,
    'user_id'       => 1234,
    'experience'    => 'Waiter'
);

$userExperience2 = array(
    'id'            => 2,
    'user_id'       => 1234,
    'experience'    => 'Chef'
);


$redis->sadd('uid:' . $userId . ':experience', json_encode($userExperience1));
$redis->sadd('uid:' . $userId . ':experience', json_encode($userExperience2));
```

I also tried using LIST

```
$redis->rpush('uid:' . $userId . ':experience', json_encode($userExperience1));
$redis->rpush('uid:' . $userId . ':experience', json_encode($userExperience2));
```

But I don't know the proper way to update specific record on redis, like I want to update only the "Waiter" experience of user 1234.

Any suggesstions or advice? Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sets you don't have other option but iterate over the set on application level.

With lists you can work with individual objects, you just need to map item id in the list to experience id. Something like this:

```
$listId = $redis->rpush('uid:' . $userId . ':experience', json_encode($userExperience1));
$redis->set('eid:' . $userExperience1['id'] . ':listId', $listId);
```

So update is quite simple:

```
$listId = $redis->get('eid:' . $newUserExperience['id'] . ':listId', $listId);
$redis->lset('uid:' . $userId . ':experience', $listId - 1, json_encode($newUserExperience));
```

but you need take extra care if you delete any experience from the list to keep the map in sync.

Comment: Cool. Thanks @Alex Blex. that's a nice way. $redis->lset('uid:' . $userId . ':experience', $listId - 1, json_encode($newUserExperience));   I put "-1" to get the proper index. For deletion, do you think its better to do a soft delete? or do you have a suggestion on how to delete specific record on the list.

Comment: Thanks, updated the answer. Yes, soft deletion is the simplest way. If you have a lot of them, you may need to "reload" the set after some threshold of deleted experiences.

Comment: got it. I will be doing the soft delete approach. thanks @Alex Blex.